# Solving optimal solution of a NLP using the Kuhn-Tucker condition

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

Consider the following NLP problem. I have solved it using KTP condition. In case II, I get $\lambda = -\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$ , but we know that according to the KTP condition $\lambda$ must be $\geq 0$. So I am confused about whether I computed the problem accurately or not.

**Question:**

Maximize $f(x,y) = xy$

Subject to, $x + y^2 \leq 2$ and $x,y \geq 0$

**Solution:**

We have,

$f(x,y) = xy$

$g(x,y) = x + y^2 - 2$

Now, $L(x,y) = xy + \lambda(x + y^2 - 2)$

The Kuhn-Tucker conditions are:

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = 0$

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = 0$

$\lambda g(x,y) = 0$

$g(x,y) \leq 0$

$\lambda \geq 0$

Applying these conditions, we get

$y + \lambda = 0$ ......... (i)

$x + 2\lambda y = 0$ ......... (ii)

$\lambda (x + y^2 - 2) = 0$ ......... (iii)

$x + y^2 - 2 \leq 0$ ......... (iv)

$\lambda \geq 0$ ......... (v)

From (iii), either $\lambda = 0$ or $x + y^2 - 2 = 0$

- Case I:

When $\lambda = 0$ , from (i) and (ii) we get $x = 0$ and $y = 0$

- Case II

When $x + y^2 - 2 = 0$ , solving (i) and (ii), we get $x = \frac{4}{3}$ , $y = \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$ and $\lambda = -\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$

$f(0,0) = 0$

$f(\frac{4}{3} , \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}) = \frac{4\sqrt{2}}{3\sqrt{3}}$

Therefore, the optimal solution is $x = \frac{4}{3}$ , $y = \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$ , which gives $f$<sub>max</sub> $= \frac{4\sqrt{2}}{3\sqrt{3}}$.

**Am I computed the NLP problem correctly?**

Comment: It looks like you also forgot to encode the conditions $x \geq 0$ and $y \geq 0$.

Comment: @cs89 yeah. But I want to know that is my result  correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are lucky and indeed obtaining the correct solution, but your derivation contains mistakes.

First, as I stated in the comment, you forgot to encode the conditions $x \geq 0$ and $y \geq 0$. These conditions are important because the objective function $xy$ can be very large while satisfying $x+y^2 \leq 2$ . For example, take $y=-n$ and $x=-n^2$. Then $x+y^2=-n^2+n^2 = 0 \leq 2$ and $xy = n^3 \gg 1$. So the objective function is unbounded when you remove the constraints $x,y \geq 0$. They are important! The fact that you obtain the correct answer without encoding them is due to the absence of *local* extremizer in the other region.

Second, as you noted, you have a problem with the sign of your multiplier. This is because you are considering a *maximization* problem, so you should set:
$$
L(x,y) := - f(x,y) + \lambda g(x,y)
$$
if your objective is to *maximize* $f$ under the constraint $g \leq 0$. See the [Karush-Kuhn-Tucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) page on Wikipedia.
All your computations remain the same, except with the opposite sign on $\lambda$, which is what you were looking for.

Even though you obtain the correct value of $f_{\max}$, please try to encode the conditions $x, y \geq 0$, at least as an instructional exercise.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. If our objective is to minimize f under g ≤ 0, then what should be the L(x,y) ? Is λ must be ≤ 0 in that case?

Comment: To minimize $f$ under $g\leq 0$, you set $L=f+\lambda g$ and $\lambda$ will be positive.

Comment: That means λ will always be positive under g≤0 ?
,

Comment: As long as you follow the sign convention used above when defining $L$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please tell me the L(x,y) is called what? What does it represent?

Comment: $L$ is called the *Lagrangian function* and you can read the [interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions#Interpretation:_KKT_conditions_as_balancing_constraint-forces_in_state_space) section of the KKT page on Wikipedia for some insight.

Comment: To maximize f under g≤0, can I set L=f-λg instead of L=-f+λg ? I found that in both the way, the answer is same

Comment: Yes. Since we are only writing first order conditions, you can use $L$ or $-L$.

Comment: can you please answer this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4693836/solve-nlp-problem-by-kuhn-tucker-condition